Flutter get data infinitely with using provider
On the splash_screen, check the cookie of the user. So, if the user login the app or already has a cookie, below code executed.
  _navigateToHome() {
    Timer(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<ExerciseProvider>(
              create: (_) => ExerciseProvider(),
              child: const HomeScreen(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

Now, I'm using flutter_provider package for handling the data easier. So I made ExerciseProvider and used notifyListners(). And then like the above code, I wrapped HomeScreen with ChangeNotifierProvider().
Below code is about provider
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workout_app/utilities/api.dart';

class ExerciseProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final List list = [];

  List getWorkoutList() {
    _fetchWorkouts();
    return list;
  }

  void _fetchWorkouts() async {
    Response res = await GetApi(apiUrl: "/workout").getData();
    final result = res.data;

    list.clear();
    list.addAll(result);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

I can use the data well, but when I print the data from this provider, the data get infinitely. (I think notifyListners() called infinitely).
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("list: ${context.watch<ExerciseProvider>().getWorkoutList()}");
    return Scaffold(
        ...


What should I do? Is it okay?

do not call getWorkoutList() in build(). This is causing continuous  fetching without stop condition. Move it to initState() and/or as callback on a button.

I called getWorkoutList() in initState(), but error occured.
FlutterError (dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<ExerciseProvider?>>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _HomeScreenState.initState() completed.
When an inherited widget changes, ...

that's a common issue with usage of provider. Follow the docs and see what’s missing.

Try replacing 'watch' with 'read'
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print("list: ${context.read<ExerciseProvider>().getWorkoutList()}");
        return Scaffold(
            ...

Explanation
The code snippet provided uses context.watch() to retrieve data from a provider. However, using watch() means the widget will listen for changes to the data and rebuild itself whenever the data changes. In this specific case, the widget is calling context.watch().getWorkoutList() inside the build() method. This triggers a chain reaction where _fetchWorkouts() is called, which in turn notifies listeners, causing the build() method to be called again, resulting in an infinite loop.
